# Auth guard with http request not working in Angular 2

Tags: angular, authentication, typescript

so I am trying to implement a guard on some routes I have in my application. So basically I want to send a http request to my api (the backend is served with express), and if my session exists, the user can access the route.

I saw a lot of examples of people doing it, and I tried all of them, but none worked. I checked the dev tools in chrome and I have no error, I just see that the request stay in the state "pending".

So what am I doing wrong? It works perfectly if I don't do a http request.

**My auth-guard.service.ts**

```
canActivate(next:  ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    return this.authService.isAuthenticated();
}
```

**And this is my auth.service.ts**

```
public isAuthenticated() : Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    let router: Router = this.router;
    let obs;

    try {
        obs = this.http.get('/api/session')
            .map(result => result.json())
            .map(resultJson => (resultJson && resultJson.success));

    } catch (err) {
        obs = Observable.of(false);
    }

    return obs
        .map(success => {
            // navigate to login page
            if (!success)
                router.navigate(['/login']);

            return success;
        });
}
```

**And here is my api function**

```
exports.getSession = function(req, res) {
     return (req.session.passport)? {success: true}: {success: false};
}
```

Comment: If you have the request pending, it probably means, that you have some backend problem, because your Angular client code gets executed when the request finishes.

Comment: You were right! the error came from my backend, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the error did not come from my Angular code... I just had to change the way I returned data in my api, like this:

```
exports.getSession = function(req, res) {
    let data = (req.session.passport)? {success: true}: {success: false};
    return res.send(data);
}
```